# how to add an array element to itself using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this particular code

```
var added_products_array = [];

$('.product tr').each(function(){
    var added_products_row = [];
    added_products_row.push($(this).find('.product_id').html());
    added_products_row.push($(this).find('.productName').html());
    added_products_row.push($(this).find('.quantity').html());
    added_products_row.push($(this).find('.units').html());
    added_products_row.push($(this).find('.unitPrice').html());
    added_products_row.push($(this).find('.discount').html());
    added_products_row.push($(this).find('.totalAmount').html());
    added_products_array.push(added_products_row);

    $.each([added_products_row[2]], function( index, value ) {  
        var store = 0;
        store += parseInt($(this));
        alert(store);
    });
});
```

.product is the tbody and the tr inside it are auto generated from another div which gives the values you see above pushed into an array.

im trying to add all td values from quantity using.each function you see above, but i cant seem to make it work. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the array and other variables each time in the loop.
Also I have removed the other loop and kept it after the first.Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Try something like this,

```
var added_products_row = [];
$('.product tr').each(function(){

        added_products_row.push($(this).find('.product_id').html());
        added_products_row.push($(this).find('.productName').html());
        added_products_row.push($(this).find('.quantity').html());
        added_products_row.push($(this).find('.units').html());
        added_products_row.push($(this).find('.unitPrice').html());
        added_products_row.push($(this).find('.discount').html());
        added_products_row.push($(this).find('.totalAmount').html());
        added_products_array.push(added_products_row);

    });

var store = 0;
$.each([added_products_row[2]], function( index, value ) {          
            store += parseInt(value);
});
alert(store);
```

Comment: rahul_m answer is much more simpler but this works too i think because its the same logic. thanks too varun!

Comment: @Dedek Yes I just made it in 2 loops to keep it simple, you can keep it one loop!